# how to get the highest resolution timeout from prototype (like scriptaculous)

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

What is the timing method and interval that scriptaculous uses in prototype for its smooth tweening?  [PeriodicalExecuter](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/ajax/periodicalupdater.html)?

Comment: This question is terrible.  Why is it so hard to type in good questions?

All that any Javascript library has to work with is the native millisecond resolution from setTimeout() and setInterval().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method**: setTimeout(), setInterval()

**Interval**: Milliseconds

You can also adjust the [frame rate that Scriptaculous uses](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/core-effects) to make animations smoother (results vary by browser and the user's machine speed unfortunately):

> fps:       Target this many frames per
>   second. Default to 25. Can’t be higher
>   than 100.

**Example**: new Effect.Fade('myDiv',{fps:60})